# Get the error "Failed to bring up eth1"

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

This is my configuration file:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static 
  address 10.0.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 10.0.1.0
  broadcast 10.0.1.255 
  gateway 10.0.1.1  
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 

auto eth1 
  iface eth1 inet static 
  address 10.0.2.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 10.0.2.0
  broadcast 10.0.2.255 
  gateway 10.0.2.1  
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove one of the gateway entries? (and or DNS entries). I do not use Ubuntu atm but speaking of general networking you usually have **one** default gateway.

Comment: Add full error message in your Q

Comment: RTNETLINK answers: File exists. Failed to bring up eth0. Ignoring unknown interface eth1=eth1

Answer (score 1):

Probably due to a conflict between two eth interfaces.

1. Let's turn off both `sudo ifdown eth0 eth1`
2. Bring up the eth0 `sudo ifup -v eth0`
3. Now the eth1 `sudo ifup -v eth1`

"v" is for verbose, that helps to get informations. Hope this helps.

Comment: It comes up with ifdown: interface eth0 not configured and interface eth1 not configured

Comment: Did you try editing your /etc/network/interfaces file? Locate the:
"iface eth0..." line and change dynamic to static
address line and change the address to the static IP address
netmask line and change the address to the correct subnet mask
gateway line and change the address to the correct gateway address
dns-nameservers line and change (or add) the nameserver information

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, if you have been fiddling with the interfaces file, especially changing it while the interface is "up", the whole config can get it's nickers in a twist, so to speak

It is not the "nicest" way but an approach that works is to make sure your interfaces file is correct and then to reboot.

also, issuing an

ip add

command (at least on 17.10), will reveal a bit of the mess you got yourself into...